# Optimizar consulta SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, revisión-de-código, optimización

Tengo la siguiente consulta SQL

```
SELECT
        (SELECT NVL(max(f_mov), '') AS f_mov
        FROM   tmp_vtas_clientes AS b
        WHERE  a.c_linea = b.c_linea
                 AND a.c_almacen = b.c_almacen
                 AND a.c_producto = b.c_referencia
                 AND a.d_producto = b.d_referencia
                 AND a.d_referencia_prov = b.d_referencia_prov
                 AND a.c_barra = b.c_barra
                 AND a.c_plu = b.c_plu
                 AND a.c_talla = b.c_talla
                 AND a.c_color_proveedor = b.c_color_proveedor
                 AND a.c_proveedor = b.c_proveedor
                 AND a.c_clasificacion = b.c_clasificacion
                 AND a.c_categoria = b.c_categoria
                 AND a.c_subcategoria = b.c_subcategoria
                 AND a.c_segmento = b.c_segmento
                 AND a.c_sector = b.c_sector
                 AND a.c_marca = b.c_marca
                 AND a.c_coleccion = b.c_coleccion
                 AND a.d_presentacion = b.d_presentacion
                 AND a.ubicacion = b.ubicacion
                 AND a.f_creacion = b.f_creacion
                 AND a.c_grupo = b.c_grupo
                 AND a.c_ciudad = b.c_ciudad)
    f_mov,
    a.c_linea,
    a.c_almacen,
    a.c_producto,
    a.d_producto,
    a.d_referencia_prov,
    a.c_barra,
    a.c_plu,
    a.c_talla,
    a.c_color_proveedor,
    a.c_proveedor,
    a.c_clasificacion,
    a.c_categoria,
    a.c_subcategoria,
    a.c_segmento,
    a.c_sector,
    a.c_marca,
    a.c_coleccion,
    a.d_presentacion,
    a.ubicacion,
    a.f_creacion,
    a.c_grupo,
    a.c_ciudad

FROM tmp_resumen1 A INTO TEMP tmp_resumen1_ventas_clientes WITH NO LOG;
```

Esta consulta tiene un tiempo de latencia muy alto y por lo general con 0 resultados existe algún modo o buenas practicas que me permita optimizar la consulta?

Comment: Podrías probar usando indices

Comment: ya intente con indices pero aun aun así es muy pesada :(

Comment: Parece una consulta normal, cuantos registros tienes ?, podrías probar particionando la tabla

Comment: Ya que preguntas sobre buenas prácticas, es mejor utilizar **JOIN** y hacer referencia entre columnas utilizando **ON**, en lugar de separar las tablas con comas y hacer referencia entre columnas en el **WHERE**.

Esto hace más leíble tu sentencia SQL.

En tu caso, habrá que ver cuantos registros tienen tus tablas, pero también puedes hacer la prueba de colocarles un **WITH (NOLOCK)** a tus tablas, para verificar si la latencia prologada que tiene tu query se debe a que alguna aplicación este bloqueando uno o más registros.

PD: Estás seguro que pegaste bien el código de tu query?

Comment: Para obtener una respuesta acertada a tu pregunta, tendrías que proporcionar mas informacion, inclyendo: Definicion de la estructura de tus tablas, cantidad de registros en cada tabla, la definicion de los índices existentes, y el "execution plan" de tu query. Sin esos detalles esenciales, solo se pueden hacer suposiciones.

Comment: De paso, si esto es Oracle, entonces el uso de `NVL(..., '')` no funciona como piensas. Tu intencion parece ser de querer convertir el valor `null` a un string vacío (`''`). Pero en Oracle, el string vacío automaticamente es convertido al valor `null`, de modo que no cambia nada. En otras palabras, diferente a otros bases de datos, en Oracle no pueden haber strings vacías.

Comment: porque no haces un stored procedure? la primera vez tardara un poco pero si se consulta de nuevo deberia tenerla ya en memoria...

Comment: Agregué la etiqueta `Oracle` siendo que tu consulta usa `NVL`, y no creo que haya otra base de datos que use `NVL`. Que alguien me corrija si estoy equivocado.

Answer (score 3):

El problema es la subconsulta, son demasiados campos a comparar .

Lo primero seria realizar un análisis de la información que debes obtener. Normalizar tu tabla para tener correctamente las **llaves foraneas** y poder unir las dos tablas.

Si la idea es obtener de las dos tablas la fecha máxima de los registros que coincidan en su información, podrías obtener todos los registros que son equivalentes con un **INTERSECT**. Obteniendo esa información obtienes el máximo registro según su fecha. Esto para obtener la fecha que obtienes de la **subconsulta**. Solo faltaría realizar un **JOIN** hacia la tabla de **tmp_resumen1** para obtener el resto de la información

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que el problema es por la subconsulta, pero no por los campos (que también puede ser por eso), sino porque esa subconsulta la ejecuta por cada registro que tiene la tabla `tmp_resumen1`.

Lo que yo haría es, por un lado ejecutar la subconsulta para ver que tira bien. Si tira bien el problema es el que te digo, que la ejecuta por cada registro de la tabla. Aún así, cruzar por tantos campos a la vez no es una buena política. Tendrías que solucionarlo utilizando claves únicas y cruzando por esas clave.

En cualquier caso, para solucionarlo como lo tienes montado te propongo una alternativa:

```
SELECT
'XXXXXXX' AS fakeField,
Tmp.f_mov,
a.c_linea,
a.c_almacen,
a.c_producto,
a.d_producto,
a.d_referencia_prov,
a.c_barra,
a.c_plu,
a.c_talla,
a.c_color_proveedor,
a.c_proveedor,
a.c_clasificacion,
a.c_categoria,
a.c_subcategoria,
a.c_segmento,
a.c_sector,
a.c_marca,
a.c_coleccion,
a.d_presentacion,
a.ubicacion,
a.f_creacion,
a.c_grupo,
a.c_ciudad
FROM tmp_resumen1 A 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT 
    'XXXXXXX' AS fakeField,
    NVL(max(f_mov), '') AS f_mov        
FROM   tmp_vtas_clientes AS b
WHERE  a.c_linea = b.c_linea
     AND a.c_almacen = b.c_almacen
     AND a.c_producto = b.c_referencia
     AND a.d_producto = b.d_referencia
     AND a.d_referencia_prov = b.d_referencia_prov
     AND a.c_barra = b.c_barra
     AND a.c_plu = b.c_plu
     AND a.c_talla = b.c_talla
     AND a.c_color_proveedor = b.c_color_proveedor
     AND a.c_proveedor = b.c_proveedor
     AND a.c_clasificacion = b.c_clasificacion
     AND a.c_categoria = b.c_categoria
     AND a.c_subcategoria = b.c_subcategoria
     AND a.c_segmento = b.c_segmento
     AND a.c_sector = b.c_sector
     AND a.c_marca = b.c_marca
     AND a.c_coleccion = b.c_coleccion
     AND a.d_presentacion = b.d_presentacion
     AND a.ubicacion = b.ubicacion
     AND a.f_creacion = b.f_creacion
     AND a.c_grupo = b.c_grupo
     AND a.c_ciudad = b.c_ciudad
)Tmp  ON a.fakeField = Tmp.fakeField
INTO TEMP tmp_resumen1_ventas_clientes WITH NO LOG;
```

Verás que lo que he hecho es resolver las consultas por separado y crear un campo ficticio para poder enganchar los dos resultados. No lo he podido probar pero creo que se entiende a lo que me refiero.

Answer (score -1):

Veamos, después de pasar la consulta un poco por el tidy veo que el problema está en la subconsulta que es demasiado pesada.

Sobre todo por **culpa de las funciones que aplicas al campo f_mov**. Piensa que las funciones aplicadas de esa manera se tienen que aplicar a todos los resultados de la consulta. En este caso como usas una subconsulta lo mejor sería aplicar dichas funciones al campo f_mov de **fuera** de la subconsulta para que así sólo se ejecutasen una sola vez.

Lo siguiente a optimizar sería el **orden del where de la subconsulta**, a no ser que el motor de base de datos que utilices sea Oracle tal y como comenta el compañero sstan, que al parecer reordena internamente los where para acelerar las consultas. Piensa que toda esa ristra de condicionantes se deben de comparar con cada uno de los campos de la tabla tmp_vtas_clientes, por lo que *lo suyo sería poner los condicionantes que más exactos sean a la hora de descartar cuanto más al principio de la ristra de ANDs*. Es decir la referencia del artículo obviamente es más específica que el almacen en el que está, porque en esa consulta seguramente tengas muchísimos productos en el mismo almacen a.c_almacen. Simplemente reordenando los AND por esta cuestión ya deberías ahorrarte bastante tiempo.

Comment: Esto no es cierto. Ejecutar la funcion no cuesta nada comparado a extraer los datos de la tabla en sí. El problema es otro. Y en cuanto al orden de las condiciones, el SQL en las bases de datos no funcionan como leguajes de programacion típicos donde las condiciones se ejecutan en orden. La base de datos (y en este caso parece ser Oracle) es lo suficientemente inteligente como para reordenar las condiciones en el orden mas eficaz de forma automatica, de modo que el orden de las condiciones no afecta en nada el rendimiento de la sentencia.

Comment: Las funciones en este caso están en el select por lo que no son tan agresivas como si estuvieran en un where, eso no te lo niego, pero lo de que el motor de base de datos reorganiza los and no te sabría decir. Puede que si algunos campos tuvieran índices el motor de base de datos los priorice, pero si no hay indices el motor de base de datos dudo que sea adivino.

Comment: A veces, sí parece adivino :), sobre todo si estamos hablando de Oracle que mantiene estadísticas sobre las tablas, como la cantidad de registros, la distribucion de las datos en las diferentes columnas, etc... Y en conjunto, esto le da una cantidad de informacion valiosa que le permite reordenar y optimizar el orden de operaciones del SQL, aun si no hay índices. Por supuesto, sin índices, el rendimiento no va a ser tan bueno, y probablemente ese sea el problema de OP. Pero el orden de las condiciones *escritas* en el SQL no afectan nada, porque Oracle los cambia automaticamente.